# Find out the percentage for each in SQL

Tags: mysql

I got two tables here, trip and users 
[image]

[image]

My question is between `Oct 1, 2013 at 10am PDT` and `Oct 22, 2013 at 5pm PDT`, what percentage of requests made by unbanned clients each day were canceled in each city?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  It would be helpful to see some actual sample data, rather than just two very large screen captures of your table definitions.

Comment: I dont have data I just got the schema thats it :/ I have created it and made some fake data on mysql tho

Comment: Then you should include this information/query in your question.

Comment: lol few fake data wont work

Comment: Is this for school project? You keep asking same/similar questions without providing any steps you took.

Comment: yaaa its a school work lol

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
SELECT 
    A.usersid,
    A.email,
    ((SELECT 
            COUNT(B.id)
        FROM
            trips B
        WHERE
            B.client_id = A.usersid
                AND request_at BETWEEN '10/1/2013' AND '10/22/2013'
                AND status <> 0) / (SELECT 
            COUNT(C.id)
        FROM
            trips C
        WHERE
            C.client_id = A.usersid
                AND request_at BETWEEN '10-1-2013' AND '10-22-2013') * 100) AS 'PERCENT'
FROM
    users A
WHERE
    A.role = 0 AND banned = FALSE
```

Comment: hii, B.id   d you mean B.client_id??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 t.city_id,
 DATE(t.request_at) AS day,
 (100*SUM(IF(t.status = 0, 0, 1))/COUNT(t.id)) AS cancellation_percentage
FROM trips t INNER JOIN users u ON t.client_id = u.users_id
WHERE u.banned = FALSE
  AND t.request_at BETWEEN '2013-10-01 17:00:00' AND '2013-10-23'
GROUP BY t.city_id, DATE(t.request_at)
```

Should produce output showing the `city_id` and percentage for each city.  This assumes that no users have been deleted or that you don't want to include trips for deleted users.  It assumes that both the numerator and denominator should exclude banned users.

The `GROUP BY t.city_id, DATE(t.request_at)` tells it that you want aggregated numbers, aggregating by the city ID and requested day.  We output the `t.city_id`, so we know which city (or at least its ID).  We exclude banned users with the where clause after joining the users table in the from clause.

We limit to between 10 AM PDT on 10/1/2013 and 5 PM PDT on 10/22/2013 in the where clause as well.  Because both those times were within daylight savings time in the United States in 2013, the offset from UTC is seven hours.  Adding that moves the latter date to the 23rd (at midnight or `00:00:00`, the default).  The former merely moves to 5 PM UTC time or `17:00:00`.

The `COUNT(t.id)` simply counts all trips requested by unbanned clients between the described date times.  The `IF(t.status = 0, 0, 1)` checks if the trip was completed.  If so it represents that as 0 trips cancelled on that trip.  If not, it counts 1 trip as cancelled on that trip.  We then sum all those, getting a count of the cancelled trips.  We divide the cancelled count by the total count and multiply the result by 100 to get the percentage.

It is possible that you are expected to do a

```
set time_zone = `PST8PDT`
```

or similar rather than changing the dates.

```
  AND t.request_at BETWEEN '2013-10-01 10:00:00' AND '2013-10-22 17:00:00'
```

These are the requested date/times in PDT.

It's possible that you should do another join to get the city name rather than ID, but there isn't enough schema information here for that.